Karate UI error -js failed: 01: click("//button[@type='button'][2]") org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "click" is not defined
Im trying to execute a simple UI execution where Im trying to login to an application and create a user.
I separated two feature files, which are login.feature and contractor.feature, where I gave tag as @reg for both feature files. I created a separate js to maintain the environmental credentials.
Here, Chrome is getting launched and logged in. feature is executed but contractor feature is failing and throwing below error.
Since I used  [And eval karate.call('Contractor.feature')] in login feature,. UI action is happening but in the cucumber report, steps from contractor.feature are getting failed when i run it with the tag. I need help here explaining why the inbuilt karate function is expected to be defined.
Cucumber Report
Cucumber Report
Error--
js failed:
>>>>
01: click("//button[@type='button'][2]")
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "click" is not defined
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)

classpath:features/Contractor.feature:20

I tried debugging why the karate predefined UI functions were not working but could not find proper solution. expecting some help to fix it. Given all the file in the description,

I'm not going to read this huge dump, but just a guess - read this part of the docs very carefully: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#javascript-function-reuse - next time please read this before asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

@PeterThomas I have updated the description above; I checked the document shared but could not find proper solution. Still, the karate function is expected to be defined. if i run the scenario on multiple feature with tag

well I have checked your question and have no idea. maybe someone else here can help. if you are serious about getting help - follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

I ran into something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78377284/calling-feature-has-referenceerror-on-steps-that-work-in-other-features-karate
