Calling Feature has ReferenceError on steps that work in other features? (Karate)
I am using Karate / Junit5 to do some UI testing. Specifically, some steps such as * waitForUrl(myUrl) give me the following error:
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: js failed:
>>>>
01: waitForUrl(sites.administrationUrl)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "waitForUrl" is not defined
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)

I follow the recommended file structure:

The LoginRunner works as intended but the PermissionRunner fails.
Content of addPermission.feature
Feature: admin adds a permission
  Background:
    * def sites = call read("classpath:sites.js")

  Scenario: login as admin
    * def result = call read('classpath:acceptance/login/loginAsAdmin.feature')
    * waitForUrl(sites.administrationUrl)


Content of loginAsAdmin.feature:
Feature: login as admin lands on permission site
  Background:
    * def sites = call read("classpath:sites.js")

  Scenario: login with admin credentials
    * def credentials = read("classpath:credentials.json").admin
    * call read('classpath:login.feature') credentials
    * waitForUrl(sites.administrationUrl)

Content of login.feature:
Feature: user login
  Background:
    * url UrlBase

  Scenario:
    Given driver UrlBase
    When method get
    Then status 200

    * input("#username", credentials.name)
    * input("#password", credentials.password)
    When submit().click("#login-button")
    Then status 200

To re-iterate, the login features work but when called from the addPermission.feature it suddenly doesn't know things like waitForUrl even though those things are used in the other features, too.
I expect addPermission.feature to know waitForUrl and other things, such as click() etc. However, all of those seem to be undefined.
Edit: It appears that the following change in addPermission.feature from * def result = call [...] to just * call [...] makes the whole thing work but I have no idea why. I would appreciat it, if anyone could elaborate on this?

isn't this the answer you are looking for: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#shared-scope - also please read this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#code-reuse

@PeterThomas I don't think so? Since my initial example used def that means that the called feature was in an isolated scope (there's a linked example). I don't see why calling it in isolation leads to things like waitForUrl suddenly not working.

ok I give up. see if you can follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue
